# How can I change the amount of video memory with a Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset?

Tags: laptop, memory, video, graphics-card

I have the chipset in the title.

The Intel control panel says the following:

Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Mobile Report

Report Date:            8/11/2010
Report Time[hr:mm:ss]:      20:2:54
Driver Version:         8.15.10.2182
Operating System:       Windows 7  (6.1.7600)
Default Language:       English (Canada)
DirectX* Version:       10.0
Physical Memory:        3963 MB
Minimum Graphics Memory:    128 MB
Maximum Graphics Memory:    1759 MB
Graphics Memory in Use:     17 MB
Processor:          Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10
Processor Speed:        1995 MHz
Vendor ID:          8086
Device ID:          2A42
Device Revision:        07

Even while playing games, the Graphics Memory in Use only ever goes up to 26 MB. I've looked in the BIOS; there's nothing there. Is there any way I can force it to go higher?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see there's a way (need) to force the "graphics memory in use" to increase. Certainly, you could write your own 3D program and use many huge textures within it to see that memory in use would increase.

Comment: If it is a graphics chip that uses "shared" memory space, then the bios is the only way to increase it, but not all bios's allow for this, most are a fixed amount these days.

Comment: The thing is, games only use 26 MB when it's obvious they need a lot more.

Comment: Why do you need to increase the memory allocated ? Increasing allocated memory does not increase the frame rates!

Comment: @Sathya A lack of video memory can cause a bottleneck though

Answer (score -1):

You can't change your video memory in a laptop. There is only one option: That is, change your motherboard and buy a new one with a more desirable graphics card.

Comment: Please stop adding `>` to every post you write. These are reserved for quotes. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that was the question. I think it is more about how to get the system to use the graphics memory fully.